# How to get elements by name in XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, linq, parsing

I've chosen the title here as my problem is I need to get the Item nodes mentioned in the example.
I have the following XML and am having problems using LINQ to query it, I've been able to parse XML before - however I've been stuck on this for hours and hope someone can help.
Here is my XML data below (example data):

```xml
<a:entry
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <a:id>98765</a:id>
    <info>Data Catalogue</info>
    <data>
        <items>
            <item>
                <id>123456</id>
                <value>Item One</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>654321</id>
                <value>Item Two</value>
            </item>
        </items>
    </data>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>123456</id>
            <value>Item One</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>654321</id>
            <value>Item Two</value>
        </item>
    </items>
    <a:author>
        <a:name>Catalogue</a:name>
    </a:author>
</a:entry>
```

I want to be able to extract the ID from the Item XML tag under Items, however there is an Items Tag with Item entries under data I DO NOT want these nodes at all - I want root/items/id/id if this were expressed as path. I've tried everything I know with LINQ so if someone could help, things to note although this is sample data it is based on the   system - the format cannot be changed so that is not an acceptable solution.
I can't seem to determine where I'm going wrong - every LINQ expression I try returns nothing, I think the namespace is an issue and have tried to integrate this but I'm going in circles.
Solution must work in Silverlight and C#

I have tried the following:

```cs
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes =
    element.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "items")
```

However this gets me all the "items" including the ones under "data" I don't want those.

---

If I do the following on my XML I do see the Names of the Elements displayed:

```cs
XElement element = XElement.Parse(data);
foreach (XElement node in element.Elements())
{
  MessageBox.Show(node.Name.LocalName);
}
```

However when I do this I cannot see the node names under items at all - I've checked the XElement and it does have the node and when I output the names above it "items" shows up along with info and id!

```cs
foreach (XElement node in element.Elements("items"))
{
  MessageBox.Show(node.Name.LocalName);
}
```

Comment: I figured it out - there was an extra namespace declaration that was blank - adding an implied namespace to my XML, using the XNamespace for this and adding it to the Element Name solves the problem!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming `element` is your `<a:entry>` element:

```
var ids = element.Element("items")
                 .Elements("item")
                 .Select(item => item.Element("id").Value);
```

The `Element` and `Elements` methods return only direct children, not all descendants, so it doesn't return the `<items>` element which is under `<data>`

Comment: This does not work, although I thought it would as this is the kind of thijng I've used before - I find that I cannot get any Elements from the root at all there was a value node off the root I've left off in the example and I cannot read it either - if I query the descendants there are some there - just don't know what's going on.

Comment: This does work once I take the namespace into account like my own answer!

Comment: You didn't provide that information in your question... I tried it using the `<a:entry>` element as the root and it worked fine.

Comment: I hadn't noticed it - nor did I think it was the issue until now, I had shortened the namespaces but didn't notice one was blank - so your answer was fine once I took this into account, and posted the version I used - which works, based on your answer, so thanks again it did help!

Answer (score 15):

I had a blank Namespace Declaration in my XML I hadn't noticed once I added this into my code it worked - forgot LINQ is very NameSpace oriented!

```
XNamespace ns = "http://example.org/namespace";
var ids = element.Element(ns + "items") 
                 .Elements("item") 
                 .Select(item => item.Element("id").Value);
```

Comment: Very helpful - wasted 2 hrs on this. Small note:  XNamespace rather than XNameSpace

Comment: I've corrected the casing on this answer based on feedback, never too late to add a corrected, eve after eight years